# How to understand this statement (measure theory)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Am reading an introductory text about measure theory. I need help in understanding the following concept ...

The text mentions two theorems. Here $m^*$ refers to the outer measure of a set:

> **Theorem 1:** If $A \subseteq B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $m^*(B)$ is finite, then $m^*(B) - m^*(A) \leq m^*(B \setminus A)$
>
> **Theorem 2:** Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a set with finite outer measure. For every $\epsilon > 0$, there is an open set $G$ such that $A \subseteq G$ and $m^*(G) < m^*(A) + \epsilon$.

Using these two theorems, the text comments afterwards:

> *... one of the tempting traps is to believe that Theorems 1 and 2 tell us something about $m^*(G \setminus A)$. For instance, Theorem 2 tells us that:*
>
> $m^*(G) - m^*(A) < \epsilon$
>
> *and Theorem 1 tells us that:*
>
> $m^*(G) - m^*(A) \leq m^*(G \setminus A)$
>
> *unfortunately, the last inequality goes in the wrong direction...*

I am trying to understand the last line of the above quotation, i.e. *the last inequality goes in the wrong direction*... I was cracking my head on what the line *goes in the wrong direction* really means ... So far, I found two ways to interpret it:

(1) It is the case that $m^*(G) - m^*(A) > m^*(G \setminus A)$. However, this does not seem to make any sense since it contradicts Theorem 1 above and goes against the additivity property of outer measure ... Theorem 1 should hold for all cases right ?

(2) $m^*(G) - m^*(A) \leq m^*(G \setminus A)$ is simply undefined. The only way I can see this if $A$ is a non-measurable set.

Among the above, I think (2) makes more sense ... but this means that given $A$ is non-measurable, then $m^*(A)$ should be some nonzero number greater than $m^*(G)$ right ? since if $m^*(A)$ is zero then it should be measurable ....

Comment: In essence, we have $a \leq b$ and $a \leq c$, but that tells us nothing about $c$ with respect to $b$.  If we had had $a \geq c$, then we get $c \leq b$, but unfortunately, we don't.

Comment: Let $G=(0,1)^n$. At one extreme is the case where $A=G $ so $m^*(A)=1$ and $m^*(G-A)=0.$ But at the other extreme is the case where $A$ is a non-measurable subset of $G$ with $m^*(A)=m^*(G-A)=1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$m^*(G) - m^*(A) \leq m^*(G \setminus A)
$$
and $$m^*(G) - m^*(A) < \epsilon$$
do not give us any information about  $$m^*(G \setminus A)$$
while the wishfull
$$m^*(G) - m^*(A) \ge m^*(G \setminus A)
$$and $$m^*(G) - m^*(A) < \epsilon$$
would have resulted in $$m^*(G \setminus A)<\epsilon.$$

Comment: thank you for your answer, but given Theorem 1, $m^*(G) - m^*(A) \geq m^*(G \setminus A)$ cannot be shown to be true in general right ?

Comment: That explains the word, unfortunately.

Comment: oh okay, I must have been confused in the semantics ... the last line should be interpreted as *unfortunately, the last inequality goes in the wrong direction since if it is $\geq$ instead of $\leq$ we could have concluded $m^*(G \setminus A) < \epsilon$ and $A$ is measurable* ... thank you !

Comment: Thanks for your attention.